# How to change Windows 7 default startup (before user log in) language?

Tags: windows, windows-7

How to change default language before user log in? I have to put english password to enter into my account but I have different input language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need admin priviledges.

Go to the Region and language settings and click the Administrative tab.  Click the Copy Settings button and select "copy settings to welcome screen and system accounts."